# sharer.php changed today? Any changelog?

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer, changelog

Do Facebook change the sharer.php support today?
Is there some kind of manual?

The preview image is not working, title and description are not working. On the preview (window with "share link") it is ok, but on the facebook title and description are taken from the actual website...

I really need simple customized link...